# Realizar consulta após conclusão de cadastro com Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

help!

Estou realizando um cadastro com AJAX e PHP, o Cadastro está OK, porém, preciso executar uma busca logo depois que o Cadastro é concluído, a estrutura é MVC:

VIEW -*cadastrarencomenda.php*

CONTROLLER - *controle-encomenda.php*

MODEL - *modelsencomenda.php*

ASSETS - *encomenda.JS*

Quando realizo o o cadastro de uma encomenda, o meu controle retorna o ID dessa encomenda cadastrada, eu quero pegar esse ID e executar logo em seguida o outro método ***LocalizarViagem($idencomenda)***, se eu colocar no navegador (http://localhost/levarte/controle-encomenda/localizaviagem/15) com o parâmetro eu consigo executar, porém, preciso que seja de forma automática para o usuário.

O meu Javascript é o que faz os POSTs.

```js
$('#form_encomendabarco').submit(function () {
 
    
 //dados encomenda aviao
   
    var datasaida = $('#datasaida').val();
    var estadoorigem = $('#estadoorigem').val();
 var estadodestino = $('#estadodestino').val(); 
 

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/levarte/controle-encomenda/salvarEncomendaBarco",
        type: "post",
        data: {
 datasaida : datasaida,
    estadoorigem : estadoorigem,
 estadodestino : estadodestino,

 },
     
      beforeSend: function () {
      
     
       alertify.message('PROCESSANDO!'); 
          
        },

        success: function (resultado) {
            if (resultado != 2) {
    
              alertify.message('LOCALIZANDO VIAGEM');
     
     ////AQUI INICIO O ENVIO DO RESULTADO QUE NA VERDADE É O IDENCOMENDA
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/levarte/controle-encomenda/localizaViagemBarco",
                    data: {
                        resultado: resultado,
                    },

                    beforeSend: function () {
                     alertify.message('LOCALIZANDO VIAGEM!');
                     alertify.message(resultado);
                    },  

                    success: function (data) {
      
      //AQUI DEVERIA CARREGAR A TELA COM O RESULTADO
      $('#content').html(resultado);
        alertify.message("VOLTOU");
               
        }
    });
```

O cadastro ocorre, mas nada depois disso.

Comment: Você não pode fazer o chamada da função dentro do próprio php? 
Ao finalizar o cadastro e com o ID do da Encomenda, chama dentro do php a function LocalizarViagem($idencomenda) dentro do próprio php e não retornando um resultado do AJAX em seguida chamar outro AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Isso porque o resultado do primeiro ajax está influenciando na execução do segundo. Evite colocar um $.ajax dentro de outro, o melhor método para fazer isso acredito que seja algo parecido com:

```
$('#form_encomendabarco').submit(function () {
        //dados encomenda aviao
        var datasaida = $('#datasaida').val();
        var estadoorigem = $('#estadoorigem').val();
        var estadodestino = $('#estadodestino').val();

        var finalResult = 0;

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/levarte/controle-encomenda/salvarEncomendaBarco",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                datasaida: datasaida,
                estadoorigem: estadoorigem,
                estadodestino: estadodestino,
            }, beforeSend: function () {
                alertify.message('PROCESSANDO!');
            }, success: function (resultado) {
                finalResult = resultado;
                if (resultado != 2) {
                    alertify.message('LOCALIZANDO VIAGEM');
                    func();
                }
            }
        });
    });

function func() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/levarte/controle-encomenda/localizaViagemBarco",
        data: {
            resultado: resultado,
        },

        beforeSend: function () {
            alertify.message('LOCALIZANDO VIAGEM!');
            alertify.message(resultado);
        },

        success: function () {

            //AQUI DEVERIA CARREGAR A TELA COM O RESULTADO
            $('#content').html(resultado);
            alertify.message("VOLTOU");

        }
    });
}
```

Porém, isso chama um $.ajax dentro de outro (através da função). Outra alterativa (o que eu acho melhor) é colocar o segundo ajax no mesmo nível do primeiro, algo como:

```
$('#form_encomendabarco').submit(function () {
    //dados encomenda aviao
    var datasaida = $('#datasaida').val();
    var estadoorigem = $('#estadoorigem').val();
    var estadodestino = $('#estadodestino').val();

    var finalResult = -1;

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/levarte/controle-encomenda/salvarEncomendaBarco",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            datasaida: datasaida,
            estadoorigem: estadoorigem,
            estadodestino: estadodestino,
        }, beforeSend: function () {
            alertify.message('PROCESSANDO!');
        }, success: function (resultado) {
            finalResult = resultado;
            if (resultado != 2) {
                alertify.message('LOCALIZANDO VIAGEM');
                func();
            }
        }
    });

    if (finalResult >= 0 && finalResult != 2) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/levarte/controle-encomenda/localizaViagemBarco",
            data: {
                resultado: resultado,
            },

            beforeSend: function () {
                alertify.message('LOCALIZANDO VIAGEM!');
                alertify.message(resultado);
            },

            success: function () {

                //AQUI DEVERIA CARREGAR A TELA COM O RESULTADO
                $('#content').html(resultado);
                alertify.message("VOLTOU");

            }
        });
    }
});
```